# npm Module Faker not creating different data when called

Tags: javascript, testing, node-modules, faker, web-api-testing

I'm creating a API test framework and using faker to create fake users to post to the API.

I'm testing two endpoints, create user and create reminder, I POST data to both of these.

To create a user I need to post a name, email and password to the user endpoint and I get back a valid JWT.

To create an reminder I need a valid JWT that I post in the header of the create reminder call.

I have a helper function that creates a user json object for me, and I use this in both the create user and create reminder endpoint.

If I run each test on its own the test will pass. However, if I try and run my full suite of tests, my validation fails on the create user endpoint because the email already exists, it was created when I called the create reminder (because this also calls the create user to get the valid token)

Here is my test to create a valid user -

```
const validUser = require('../data/userData/validUser');

describe('Functional Testing', () => {
  describe('Users', () => {
    it('It should create a user', async () => {
      const response = await usersService.createUser(validUser);
      expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
      expect(response.body).to.not.be.null;
      expect(response.body).to.have.deep.property('token');
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the reminder test that users the user service for the token

```
context('Functional Testing', () => {
  describe('Reminder', () => {
    it.skip('It should create a reminder', async () => {
      const createUserResponse = await user.createUser(validUser);
      const token = createUserResponse.body.token;

      const response = await reminderService.createReminder(
        validReminder,
        token
      );

      expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(201);
      expect(response.body).to.have.deep.property('success');
      expect(response.body).to.deep.include({ success: 'reminder created' });
    });
```

And here is my module that creates the user -

```
const faker = require('faker');

module.exports = {
  name: 'Test User',
  email: `${faker.internet.email()}`,
  password: '123123'
};
```

I would have thought that regardless, the createUser module would always create me a random email, but I think the tests might be running to fast for faker to generate a new random email?

How do I get Faker to always generates a random user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have at least 2 options:

1. you invalidate the valid user module removing it from the cache
2. you use a getter for your user

**Invalidating the module**

A module can be required dozen times but it will only export once. Any data with it will execute once, including the faking email.

However, with CommonJS you can delete modules from the cache:

```js
const vuPath = require.resolve('../data/userData/validUser');
console.log(require(vuPath));
console.log(require(vuPath));
// same result ... now
delete require.cache[vuPath];
console.log(require(vuPath));
// different email
```

This requires that you invalidate the user every time, or you teardown the invalidation and reassign the `validUser` on setup.

**Using a getter**

```js
const faker = require('faker');

module.exports = {
  name: 'Test User',
  get email() { return faker.internet.email(); },
  password: '123123'
};
```

In this case the user will have a different email each time `user.email` is accessed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I decided to go with the getter option, as this kept my code cleaner and easier to read. I'm just starting out with writing javascript. 

Can I ask how you know this, I looked at the faker docs and didn't see this. Or is this a generic javascript thing?